# How to create a charts in Razor Pages pulling data from the database?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, charts, chart.js, razor-pages

How do I create charts pulling from the database? I've tried MorrisJS, ChartJS, CanvasJS, HighCharts. But I think the closest I got is with ChartJS so hopefully we can stick to that.

I need to create a chart that pulls data from the db and using more than 1 table in the database, for example, Database name "Finance", I need a  bar chart that compares sum of Amount in dbo.Revenue and Sum of Amount in dbo.Expense by month. Month is the x-axis. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vupg4.png) , but I did this manually by adding the values in the code.

What I have tried to do to pull from the db, ar is the table name (revenue)

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetRevenueData()
        {
            ar21 =  await _context.ar21.ToListAsync();
            var arChart = new arChartModel();
            arChart.AmountList = new List<decimal?>();
            arChart.CategoryList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var r in ar21)
            {
                arChart.AmountList.Add(r.Amount);
                arChart.MonthList.Add(r.Month);
            }

            return new JsonResult(arChart);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Revenue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}
public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}
```

Page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<canvas id="Chart1" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
   
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js" integrity="sha256-qSIshlknROr4J8GMHRlW3fGKrPki733tLq+qeMCR05Q=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xKeoJ50pzbUGkpQxDYHD7o7hxe0LaOGeguUidbq6vis=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.css" integrity="sha256-IvM9nJf/b5l2RoebiFno92E5ONttVyaEEsdemDC6iQA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js" integrity="sha256-arMsf+3JJK2LoTGqxfnuJPFTU4hAK57MtIPdFpiHXOU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/?handler=RevenueData",   
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.revenue);
                    console.log(response.revenue.length);
                    var data = response.revenue;
                    var data2 = response.expense;
                    var labels = response.month;
                    var color1 = [];
                    var color2 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.month.length; i++)
                    {
                        color1.push("rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)");
                        color2.push("rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)");
                    }
  
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Revenue',
                                data: data,
                                backgroundColor: color1,
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'Expense',
                                data: data2,
                                backgroundColor: color2
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive: false,
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        maxRotation: 90,
                                        minRotation: 80
                                    },
                                    gridLines: {
                                        offsetGridLines: true 
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    position: "top",
                                    ticks: {
                                        maxRotation: 90,
                                        minRotation: 80
                                    },
                                    gridLines: {
                                        offsetGridLines: true 
                                    }
                                }],
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                  
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Handler:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public JsonResult OnGetRevenueData()
    {
        var countRevenue = (from t in _context.Revenue
                           group t by new
                           {
                               Month = t.Month
                           } into g
                           select  g.Sum(a=>a.Amount)
                           ).ToArray();
        var countExpense = (from t in _context.Expense
                            group t by new
                            {
                                Month = t.Month
                            } into g
                            select g.Sum(a => a.Amount)
                           ).ToArray();
        var monthList = _context.Revenue.Select(a => a.Month).Distinct().ToArray();
        return new JsonResult(new { revenue = countRevenue, expense = countExpense, month = monthList });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much.

Question:
What if I have something like payroll to add into my spending, do I do

`var countPayroll = (from p in _context.payroll group p by new Month = p.Month} into g select g.Sum(a => a.Amount)).ToArray();`

How do I then add payroll and expense together?

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, what do you mean add them together with? Did you want to configure like `return new JsonResult(new{payroll=countPayroll , expense= countExpense})`?

Comment: Hmm like `JsonResult(new{spendings=countPayroll + countExpense})` or a way to add in Linq? Payroll and Expense have JobNum which is like ID, should I join them in Linq first?

Comment: It seems you want to sum the payroll and Expense which have the same ID? If so, I think you could join them first in linq. I suggest you could share the model design and your expected result to create a new thread.

Comment: Hi Rena, I have made a detailed version including working with your currently solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/67981914/15397944

Comment: Ok. Let me check.