# How to sort MMMYY on Chart.Js and display the values that match the month?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, chart.js, razor-pages

this is going to be long and may get confusing but please bear with me.

My previous question I asked how to pull data from the database and display it in charts dynamically, I have managed to do it courtesy of @Rena. This is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67967555/15397944.
I am currently facing some challenges now, I would split my question into two parts but first I will show my model design.

Model

```
public class payable
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Month {get; set;}
}

public class receivable
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Month {get; set;}
}

public class payroll
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Month {get; set;}
}

public class year
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Month {get; set;}
}
```

In the database, the tables have different values in different months.

For example if I call sum amount in **payable**, group by month and select month distinct, I would get something like

```
+-------+-------+
| JUL20 | $400  |
+-------+-------+
| SEP20 | $200  |
+-------+-------+
| OCT20 | $300  |
+-------+-------+
| DEC20 | $2000 |
+-------+-------+
| JAN21 | $1910 |
+-------+-------+
| FEB21 | $900  |
+-------+-------+
| MAR21 | $203  |
+-------+-------+
| APR21 | $194  |
+-------+-------+
| MAY21 | $1000 |
+-------+-------+
```

But if I do the same thing for **receivable**, I would get something like

```
+-------+-------+
| DEC20 | $1939 |
+-------+-------+
| JAN21 | $191  |
+-------+-------+
| FEB21 | $430  |
+-------+-------+
| MAR21 | $135  |
+-------+-------+
| APR21 | $945  |
+-------+-------+
| MAY21 | $1240 |
+-------+-------+
```

There are some old months from 2020 in some table but I only want my charts to show those of 2021, hence, the reason I created the table Year, to simply have Jan - Present month in 2021, the string is shown as MMMYY (e.g. JAN21). So then this creates an issue for me when displaying charts because I am unsure how to show only if payable.month = year.month

So here is part 1, in the charts I would simply like something like this:
[image] where Expense = payable + payroll.

But I was not able to do that which was fine for me, I could simply call all 3 and display them in 3 different charts which is okay for my project solution as well.

However, here is part 2. Following the solution, when I change the Handler method for month list to the respective tables or the year table, I will get a jumble of the months (arranged alphabetically) but then that means the the other two tables will be arranged wrongly.

```
    public JsonResult OnGetRevenueData()
    {
     <!-- Code omitted to shorten -->
        var monthList = _context.year.Select(a => a.Month).Distinct().ToArray();
        return new JsonResult(new { revenue = countRevenue, expense = countExpense, month = monthList });
    }
}
```

For example, Receivable chart would look like this[image]

Because the data is followed according to this [image]
And I know this because I got this by changing the code to

```
    public JsonResult OnGetRevenueData()
    {
     <!-- Code omitted to shorten -->
        var monthList = _context.receivable.Select(a => a.Month).Distinct().ToArray();
        return new JsonResult(new { revenue = countRevenue, expense = countExpense, month = monthList });
    }
}
```

As you can see it is simply following the array, so even if for the first image where the label of months follow the year table, and I OrderBy(year.Id) which would give me JAN-MAY correctly, the values would not follow as JAN would then be receivable's FEB and FEB would then become APR so on and so forth.

So my questions are, is there a way to achieve part 1, where the month of receivable, payable and payroll table match the year table months which is the label for the chart. Otherwise, is it possible to do it in part 2 instead?

Any help is much appreciated and thank you for reading until the end.

---

### Edit: After implementing solution but the numbers do not tally with DataTables as well as Database SQL.

As you can see, for DataTables I filtered it to show MAR21, and using footerCallback I summed the values in the column Amount, which gives me the correct sum
[image]

footerCallback code

```
"footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) 
{
   var api = this.api(), data;
   var numberRenderer = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$').display;
// Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
   var intVal = function (i) 
{
   return typeof i === 'string' ? 
      i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
         typeof i === 'number' ?
            i : 0;
};

   Total = api
      .column(4, { page: 'current' })
      .data()
      .reduce(function (a, b) {
      return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0);
   $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
      'Total : ' + numberRenderer(Total)
   );
}
```

This is confirmed that it is right by comparing it with the database itself using SQL
[image]

However, on the solution after the graph is implemented, this is what I got
[image]
Image shows number to be 757210.83.

As you can see from the screenshot as well, the MAY column doesn't have expense but in fact in the Database there are values.

Upon checking further, the value 757210.83, belongs to May.
So the values are summing correctly but displaying wrongly. MAY numbers shown on MAR column and MAR numbers showing on MAY column. The others as well - JAN numbers showing on APR column, FEB numbers showing on JAN column, APR numbers showing on FEB column. So, I'm pretty confused as to why it is the way it is, it isn't sorted by alphabetical either since APR number isn't in JAN column.

But this still does not explain the missing Expense column as all of them have expense (payroll and/or payable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your linq like below:

```
public JsonResult OnGetRevenueData()
{
    var year = _context.year.Select(a => a.Month).ToList();
    var Revenue = (from t in _context.Revenue
                    where year.Contains(t.Month)
                    group t by new {  Month = t.Month} into g                              
                    select new 
                    {
                        Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                        Month = g.Key.Month
                    }).ToList();
    var countRevenue = Revenue.OrderBy(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.Month, "MMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
                                .Select(a=>a.Amount)
                                .ToList();
    var countPayroll = (from t in _context.payroll
                        where year.Contains(t.Month)
                        group t by new { Month = t.Month } into g
                        select new {
                            Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                            Month = g.Key.Month
                        }).ToList();
    var countPayable = (from t in _context.payable
                        where year.Contains(t.Month)
                        group t by new { Month = t.Month } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                            Month = g.Key.Month
                        }).ToList();
      //change here......
    var leftOuterJoin = from a in countPayable
                        join b in countPayroll on a.Month equals b.Month into temp
                        from count in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            Month = a.Month,
                            Amount = a.Amount
                        };
    var rightOuterJoin =
        from b in countPayroll
        join a in countPayable on b.Month equals a.Month into temp
        from count in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            Month = b.Month,
            Amount = b.Amount
        };
    var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);
    var Expense = (from t in fullOuterJoin
                    group t by new
                    {
                        Month = t.Month
                    } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                        Month = g.Key.Month
                    }
                    ).ToList();
    var countExpense = Expense.OrderBy(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.Month, "MMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
                                .Select(a => a.Amount)
                                .ToList();

    var yearList = ((from y in _context.year
                        select y.Month
                        )
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month)
                    ).ToArray();
    return new JsonResult(new { revenue = countRevenue, expense = countExpense, month = yearList });
}
```

Result:

Bar Chart:

[image]

payable table:

[image]

payroll table:

[image]

Revenue table:

[image]

year table:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm, and it is amazing. I cannot thank you enough. I believe this is the solution, however, strangely the graph numbers aren't right. For example, because in the tables itself I am using DataTables and the footercallback function to sum the column Amount, for example, Revenue MAR21 the sum is $3,197,429.90 in DataTables but on the graph it only plot $757,210.83. Real strange.

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, Hmm It seems to be another question? Could you please share more details? Also what is your datatable? How do you sum the column amout?

Comment: Hi @Rena, I edited my question to explain why the sum numbers are wrong

Comment: Ok, I understand. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Thank you so much for that. It finally works now. Only thing is May is missing which is odd because the Expense for all other months add up. May does not have payroll yet but there is a sum in payable, does this make a difference?

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey,Please check my updated answer.

Comment: `var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);`  gets error on leftOuterjoin
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Month, decimal? Amount>>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Union<<anonymous type: string Month, decimal Amount>>(ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: string Month, decimal Amount>>,IEnumerable<<anonymous type: string Month, decimal Amount>>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<<anonymous type: string Month, decimal Amount>>'`

Comment: From the error message, it seems the type of Amount in two models are not the same. Please be sure they are all the same type as `decimal` or `decimal?`.

Comment: For easy understanding, the Amount property in `payroll` and `payable` should be the same type. `deciaml` and `decimal?` are different types.

Comment: Alright, you were right about the error, after changing it there was no error but the May Expense still does not show up. Could it be anything to do with the chart? Because even before you fixed the ordering of the month, the expense in May (which was not May) did not show up.

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, please firstly check if `countPayroll` or `countPayable` has such value in May. Then you said the expense which is not May did not shown up, did you see the chart have the date? Or it has the date but do not have the bar?

Comment: Hello, yes countPayable has value in May. So if you refer to my question where I edited and showed the screenshot when the graph is implemented but arranged wrongly, May column did not show any expense - but for all months there is expense. After arranging correctly, all other months showed the expense correctly but for May, there is no bar

Comment: Hi @FlyingSpiderMonkey, If all the months have correct value in chart, and it does not have value after ordering by month. I think you need check the Month data if it is `MAY21` or `MAY20` in database. Actually you said you only want 2021 year's data.

Comment: Also, I have shared the whole database data and bar chart image. You could see that it all displays correctly.

Comment: Okay it is working now, this was waaay harder than I thought and I was not close at all hahah. I cannot thank you enough. You have been tremendous help. Thank you Rena!